# Why can't I recover my Pokemon Go password, even though I can recover my username just fine?

Tags: pokemon-go

After I fill the form that they have [here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/forgot-password), 
this message pops up right under my email:

> Unable to find an account using the provided information.

When I try to retrieve my username and use that same email, there is no problem; I receive an email with my username, so why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

On the PTC password recovery form, the only required field is the one for email. However, entering incorrect information into one of the *other* fields will cause the request to fail. Confusingly, the message that indicates this failure will point at email, even though the problem is with a different field.

For instance, I navigated to the site on a mobile device/browser, and noticed that the birthday field was "helpfully" filled in, automatically, with today's date. I was not able to invoke a password change request until I cleared the information from that field.